# How best to access a static method that can run different implementations of the same method?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a clean way to run a method that could have different implementations from within a static method.

The reason for this requirement is that I would like access to a static method A that will always call method B. The implementation of method B however might be different.

Simple example of the code is as follows.....

```
public class PageFactory
{
    public static void InitializeElements()
    {
        new PageFactory().Initialize();
    }

    public virtual void Initialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Page factory initialize");
    }
}

public class SepaPageFactory : PageFactory
{
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SEPA Factory initialize");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // "Page factory initialize"

        PageFactory.InitializeElements();

        // I would like to see "SEPA Factory initialize here"

        SepaPageFactory.InitializeElements();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Obviously `SepaPageFactory.InitializeElements();` doesn't return the result I would like.

This is the first option I considered

```
public static void InitializeElements(PageFactory factory)
{
    factory.Initialize();
}
```

And then do...

```
PageFactory.InitializeElements(new PageFactory());
PageFactory.InitializeElements(new SepaPageFactory());
```

Also I could do...

```
public static void InitializeElements<T>() where T : PageFactory, new()
{
    new T().Initialize();
}
```

And...

```
PageFactory.InitializeElements<PageFactory>();
PageFactory.InitializeElements<SepaPageFactory>();
```

Is there a better way of achieving this?

I'm open to any design suggestions that solve this problem.

**EDIT**

I'll try to describe the actual use case.....

This is to be part of a test automation framework where elements on a webpage are represented by fields in a class. These 'page' classes can have upwards of 50 elements that all require instantiating. As they all have the same constructor parameters, a quick and clean way to do this (IMO) is with reflection.

The 'real' initialize method will be used to reflect over and instantiate certain fields on these pages.

Using my generics implementation above it would look like...

```
public static void InitializeElements<U,T>(IWebDriver driver, T page) where U : PageFactory, new()
{
    new U().Initialize(driver, page);
}

public virtual void Initialize<T>(IWebDriver driver, T page)
{
    var pageType = typeof(T);

    const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | 
                                BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

    foreach (var field in pageType.GetFields(flags))
    {
        var findsByAttribute = (FindsByAttribute)field.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(FindsByAttribute));
        var frameAttribute   = (FrameLocatorAttribute)field.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(FrameLocatorAttribute));

        var fieldType = field.FieldType;

        if (fieldType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Control)) || fieldType == typeof(Control))
        {
            field.SetValue(page,
                frameAttribute != null
                    ? InitializeControls<Control>(field, driver, findsByAttribute, frameAttribute)
                    : InitializeControls<Control>(field, driver, findsByAttribute));                   
        }
    }
}
```

`U` in this context is the class that provides the implementation of the Initialize method.

Most of the time this implementation will be sufficient, however on occasion there will different constraints on which field types are instantiated, hence the need for virtual/override.

This would then be used in the constructor of the pages where I wish to initialise all my fields, e.g....

```
public class LoginLinkPage : BasePage<LoginLinkPage>
{
    [FindsBy(".content a[href='/Account/SignIn']", How.CssSelector)]
    public Control LoginLink;

    public LoginLinkPage(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver)
    {
        PageFactory.InitializeElements<SepaPageFactory, LoginLinkPage>(driver, this);
    }
}
```

Which I would like to be consistent regardless of which implementation of Initialize is to be used.

Comment: I like the approach that makes use of generic types

Comment: what about just adding static method InitializeElements() inside class SepaPageFactory?

Comment: Can you explain the reason for this construct? Seems that the problem behind it could be solved with basic polymorphis ond/or standard design patterns. What solution fits best though depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I'm also curious as to the use case here - based on that, another approach might be more useful if you are considering something akin to "static inheritance" like this.

Comment: Do you know type at compile time? Then generics fits. If you are going to enumerate unknown types (`ISomeType`), then call this method directly yourself (`ISomeType.Initialize()`) or pass something (type, instance, delegate) into static method, so it will do it for you. Details are matter, since you provide too little - that's going to be opinion based answer.

Comment: Since the method doesn't return anything, are you sure you don't just want to use the static constructor of each type for this? Do you need to explicitly control when this happens?

Comment: @Sefe I've edited my post to include a use case. Test automation isn't widely known about so the 'why' may still not be entirely clear, but at least you can hopefully see what I'm wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this shouldn't be the best way, but you can also do something like this:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public static void DoWork(int a)
        {
        }
    }

    public class Doh : Foo
    {
        public **new** static void DoWork(int a)
        {
        }
    }
```

That should "override" the method, but maybe it would be better to think about different approach :)